# Continuous functions and metric topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X = C[0, 1]$ be the set of all continuous functions $f : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R}$ (where the domain and codomain have their usual topologies). Let $d_1 : X \times X \to \Bbb{R}$ be the metric on $X$ given by
$$
d_1(f, g) = \int_0^1 
\left| f(x) − g(x) \right| \, dx.
$$
Show that the function $F : X \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ given by $F(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ is continuous (where $X$ has the metric topology generated by $d_1$, and $\Bbb{R}$ has its usual metric topology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left|\int_{[0,1]}(f-g) \ dx \right| \leq \int_{[0,1]} |f-g| \ dx$$

Answer (score 2):

To show that $F$ is continuous in the metric topology, we must show that given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$
d_1(f, g) < \delta \implies |F(f) - F(g)| < \varepsilon.
$$
As @Faraad says, the trick is to use the inequality $\left| \int_0^1 u \right| \leq \int_0^1 |u|$. Then we can just pick $\delta = \varepsilon$, since 
$$
d_1(f, g) < \varepsilon \implies \varepsilon > \int_0^1 |f-g| \geq \left| \int_0^1 f-g \right| = \left| F(f) - F(g) \right|,
$$
which can be shortened to 
$$
d_1(f, g) < \varepsilon \implies |F(f) - F(g)| < \varepsilon
$$
as desired.